# Shape of my modelHead changing from edit mode to object mode

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

I managed to rig my model. It uses long chains with some constraints for both ik and fk kinematics. But now, I have faced another challenge. I have tried to fix this, but I'm missing something. In edit mode, the shape of my head is perfectly circular, but it changes to some weird shape. How do I fix this?[image: edit mode]

[image]

[image: Object mode]

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: A share on https://blend-exchange.com/ would probably clear this up more quickly than a blindfolded exchange of details in  the commentary :)

Comment: @chris I just did

Comment: @RobinBetts  I just did...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things here: your neck is rotated in *Pose* mode, it makes the head deform because the top neck bone also influences the head mesh. You could remove the vertices from this neck vertex group, or keep it, and when you want the head to rotate, rotate this neck bone a little bit as well, this way . More generally, I'm not sure why you use so many faces and so many bones.

Comment: Oh, thank you...  I am not sure how to reduce the number of faces... I have tried all methods help me out here....